# Gedit syntax-highlighting with gtksourceview for backreferencing sub-patterns?

Tags: c, syntax-highlighting, gnome, gedit, gtksourceview

The following will highlight "timeout" on the second line but will not highlight it ever again. Does gtksourceview support some sort of backreference on the "sub-pattern" that will match all instances throughout the file ?

[gtksourceview website manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html)

/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/c.lang

```html
<context id="struct" style-ref="struct">
     <match>\bstruct\b\s\w+\s(\w+)</match>
          <include>
               <context sub-pattern="1" style-ref="structname"/>
          </include>
</context>
```

```c
int ns;
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 1;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

setsockopt(ns, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
setsockopt(ns, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, [the requested functionality is not supported](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/2012-March/msg00011.html) at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do stateless highlighting in GtkSourceView. Perhaps you can do something with recursive contexts? Capture everything after the second line in your `struct` context, then highlight your struct name, plus call the main context recursively. I'm not sure whether this would work though.